# С# - mySQL и .NET Core 2.0

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, .net-core

Всем привет! Есть нужна использовать БД в проекте .NET Core 2.0.
Знаком с БД mySQL. И собственно сам вопрос: Можно ли использовать и как нибудь подлючить  mySQL к проекту на .NET Core 2.0? Проект является кросс-платформенным, т.е. нужно, чтобы БД работала на Linux Ubuntu и на Microsoft Windows.
Если такое не возможно, тогда какие аналоги есть? И если можно, ссылку на документацию.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону [EntityFramework Core](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjyo6_KvOrVAhXMZpoKHRfUA70QFggvMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fblogs.msdn.microsoft.com%2Fdotnet%2F2017%2F08%2F14%2Fannouncing-entity-framework-core-2-0%2F&usg=AFQjCNGHO7WpGBJfjeoZJM2oXMTwc5e5Jw)

Answer (score 2):

можно воспользоваться EntityFramework Core. [Здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/) официальная документация. Там же можно посмотреть о новшествах EF Core 2.0, [а здесь русскоязычная документация](https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframeworkcore/)

Подключить довольно просто: создаём класс, который наследуем от DbContext, в нём определяем классы через DbSet, которые будут нашими таблицами, после создаём миграции. Вот пример создания собственного контекста. В методе `OnModelCreating` определяются отношения "Многие ко многим" **(здесь используется подключение к UWP. Отличия только в способе подключения БД, в методе `OnConfiguring`)**

```
using Library.Core.Models.Entity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Library.Core.DataBase
{
    public class LibraryContext : DbContext
    {
        #region Properties
        /// <summary>
        /// Авторы. 
        /// </summary>
        public DbSet<Author> Authors { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Издательства. 
        /// </summary>
        public DbSet<Publishing> Publishers { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Контракты. 
        /// </summary>
        public DbSet<Contract> Contracts { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Книги. 
        /// </summary>
        public DbSet<Book> Books { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Читательские билеты. 
        /// </summary>
        public DbSet<Reader> Readers { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Записи в билете. 
        /// </summary>
        public DbSet<Record> Records { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Отделы. 
        /// </summary>
        public DbSet<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
        #endregion


        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Filename=library.db");
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Record>()
                .HasKey(r => new { r.BookId, r.ReadersId });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Contract>()
                .HasKey(c => new { c.AuthorId, c.PublishingId });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Record>()
                .HasOne(rc => rc.Book)
                .WithMany(b => b.Records)
                .HasForeignKey(rc => rc.BookId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Record>()
                .HasOne(rc => rc.Readers)
                .WithMany(r => r.Records)
                .HasForeignKey(rc => rc.ReadersId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Contract>()
                .HasOne(cn => cn.Author)
                .WithMany(a => a.Contracts)
                .HasForeignKey(cn => cn.AuthorId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Contract>()
                .HasOne(cn => cn.Publishing)
                .WithMany(p => p.Contracts)
                .HasForeignKey(cn => cn.PublishingId); 
        }
    }
}
```

Пример одной таблицы:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using Template10.Mvvm;

namespace Library.Core.Models.Entity
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Книга. 
    /// </summary>
    public class Book : BindableBase
    {
        private string _name;
        private int _price;
        private int _count;
        private Genre _genre;
        private Contract _contract;
        private bool _selected; 

        public Book()
        {
            Records = new ObservableCollection<Record>(); 
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Id книги. 
        /// </summary>
        public int Id { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Название книги. 
        /// </summary>
        public string Name
        {
            get => _name;
            set => Set(ref _name, value); 
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Кол-во книг. 
        /// </summary>
        public int Count
        {
            get => _count;
            set => Set(ref _count, value);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Стоимость книги. 
        /// </summary>
        public int Price
        {
            get => _price;
            set => Set(ref _price, value);
        }

        [NotMapped]
        public bool IsSelected
        {
            get => _selected;
            set => Set(ref _selected, value); 
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Идентификатор контракта. 
        /// </summary>
        public int? ContractId { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Автор-Издательство. 
        /// </summary>
        public Contract Contract
        {
            get => _contract;
            set => Set(ref _contract, value);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Айди раздела. 
        /// </summary>
        public int? GenreId { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Раздел книги. 
        /// </summary>
        public Genre Genre
        {
            get => _genre;
            set => Set(ref _genre, value);
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Record> Records { get; set; }
    }
}
```